# Scrapy keeps crawling and never stops... CrawlSpider rules

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm very new to python and scrapy and decided to try and built a spider instead of just being scared of the new/challenging looking language.

So this is the first spider and it's purpose :

- It runs through a website's pages (through links it finds on every
  page)
- List all the links (a>href) that exist on every page
- Writes down in each row: the page where the links were found, the links themselves
  (decoded+languages), number of links on every page, and http response code of every link.

The problem I'm encountering is that it's never stopping the crawl, it seems stuck in a loop and always re-crawling every page more then once...

What did I do wrong? (obviously many things since I never wrote a python code before, but still)
How can I make the spider crawl every page only once?

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
import urllib.parse
import requests
import threading


class TestSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "test"
    allowed_domains = ["cerve.co"]
    start_urls = ["https://cerve.co"]
        rules = [Rule (LinkExtractor(allow=['.*'], tags='a', attrs='href'), callback='parse_item', follow=True)]
    
        def parse_item(self, response):
             alllinks = response.css('a::attr(href)').getall()
             for link in alllinks:
                 link = response.urljoin(link)
                 yield {
                    'page': urllib.parse.unquote(response.url),
                    'links': urllib.parse.unquote(link),
                    'number of links': len(alllinks),
                    'status': requests.get(link).status_code
                 }
```

Comment: You can Try this attribute of link extractor : unique (boolean) – whether duplicate filtering should be applied to extracted links. If not work , you may filter links by using "process_links" callback

Comment: thanks @akash , I tried adding the unique part like that:
rules = [Rule (LinkExtractor(allow=['.*'], tags='a', attrs='href', unique=True), callback='parse_item', follow=True)]

It doesn't work.

About using the process links, how do you use that in order to filter duplicates?
or if there is a good tutorial or guide to help me with that, I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Scrapy said :***
By default, Scrapy filters out duplicated requests to URLs already visited. This can be configured by the setting `DUPEFILTER_CLASS`.

***Solution 1 :***   https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#std-setting-DUPEFILTER_CLASS

***My experience with your code :***
There are so many links . And i did not see any duplicates urls being visited twice.

***Solutions 2 in worst case***
In `settings.py` set `DEPTH_LIMIT`= some number of your choice

Comment: Thanks friend, it works as you said, it just take a very long time. if I will use proxies with increased requests per domain/ip and lower download delay, would the scraping be faster?

Comment: Sure.You can also increase concurrent request. But you have to make sure that the site allows so many frequent request from bot

Comment: Thanks @akash, I appreciate it.